# Is differential geometry related to partial differential equations?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I am doing my PhD in real analysis and besides I am studying differential geometry. I have heard that differential geometry is related to PDE. Can anyone please suggest me some books regarding this? I am also interested to know what kind research work are going on this topic.

Comment: Take a look at [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Differential-Geometry-2010-re-issue/dp/1571461981). PDE is everywhere. And you may ask anyone working in [geometric analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_analysis) to give you several examples. But the fields is too big to be simply summarized.

Comment: There’s also general relativity.

Answer (score 1):

An important part of the study of PDE's can also be formulated in the context of jet manifolds/bundles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_bundle#Partial_differential_equations

Answer (score 0):

A foliation is often defined by differential equations. see D p. 372 here

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183535509